# cannot find database driver oracle.jdbc.oracledriver while running liquibase in cmd

Tags: liquibase

/*i am trying to execute normal  liquibase command for changelog in commandprompt but it is saying driver not exist*/

liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --classpath=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar --changeLogFile=db.changelog-1.0.xml --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" --username=system --password=root update

/*please any one tell me why throwing oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver not found*/

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver \
 --classpath=ojdbc6.jar \
```

....

Answer (score 0):

I had to use:

```
--driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please inlcude odbc jar in your property file. 
Like:

driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
classpath: ojdbc6-2.0.jar

This will work.